# How Akka Actors are clearing resources?

Tags: scala, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, akka, akka-actor

We're experiencing strange memory behavior on our web server built using Akka HTTP.
Our architecture goes like this:

1. web server routes calls various actors, get results for future and streams it to response
2. actors call non-blocking operations (using futures), combine and process data fetched from them and pipe results to sender. We're using standard Akka actors, implementing its receive method (not Akka typed)
3. there is no blocking code anywhere in the app

When I run web server locally, at the start it takes around 350 MB. After first request, memory usage jumps to around 430 MB and slowly is increasing with each request (monitored using Activity Monitor on Mac). But shouldn't GC clean things after each request? Shouldn't memory usage after processing be 350 MB again?

I also installed YourKit java profiler and here is a digram of head memory

[image: .]

It can be seen that once memory usage increase, it never goes back, and system is stateless. Also, when I run GC manually from profiler, it almost doesn't do anything, just a small decrease in memory usage. I understand some services might cache things after first request, consuming memory temporarily, but is there any policy inside Akka Actors or Akka HTTP about this?

I tried to check objects furthest from GC but it only shows library classes and Akka built in classes, nothing related to our code.

So, I have a 2 questions:

1. How the actor is closing resources and freeing memory after message processing? Did you experienced anything similar?
2. Is there any better way of profiling Akka HTTP which will show me stacktrace of using classed furthest from GC?

On a side note, is it advisable to use scheduler inside Actors (running inside Akka HTTP server)? When I do that, it seems memory usage increases heavily and app runs our of memory on DEV environment.

Thanks in advance,

Amer

Comment: do you create actors with each request or reusing them?

Comment: and if you create new actors - are you killing the old ones?

Comment: I'm reusing them. I'm creating actors at server start and reusing same actors all the time. There are 6 various actors

Comment: what is the actual problem here? From the screen of Heap Memory that you showed, you are consuming a small portion of the total heap. When GC is triggered depends on the actual GC algorithm that you use and java-version and it's configuration. You also have to make a distinction between `committed` and `resident` memory. Those `430 MB` "and slowly increasing" is most probably `committed` memory

Answer (score 0):

An actor remains active until it is explicitly stopped: there is no garbage collection.

Probably the two most common methods for managing actor lifetimes (beyond the actor itself deciding that it's time to stop) are:

- Parent is responsible for stopping children.  If the actors are being spawned for performing specific tasks on behalf of the parent, for instance, this approach is called for.
- Using an inactivity timeout.  If the actors represent domain entities (e.g. an actor for every user account, where this actor in some sense serves as an in-memory cache), using `context.setReceiveTimeout` to  cause a `ReceiveTimeout` message to be sent to the actor after the timeout has passed (note that in some cases the scheduled send of that message may not be canceled in time if a message was enqueued in the mailbox but not processed when the timeout expired: receiving a `ReceiveTimeout` is not a guarantee that the timeout has passed since the last received message) is a pretty reasonable solution, especially if using Akka Persistence and Akka Cluster Sharding to allow the actor's state to be recovered.

Update to add:

Regarding

> shouldn't GC clean things after each request?

The short answer is no, GC will not clean things after each request (and if it does, that's a very good sign that you haven't provisioned enough memory).

The longer answer is that the characteristics of garbage collection on the JVM are very underspecified: the only rule a garbage collection implementation has to respect is that it never frees an object reachable from a GC root (basically any variable on a thread's stack or static to a class) by a chain of strong references.  When and even whether the garbage collector reclaims the space taken up by garbage is entirely implementation dependent (I say "whether" to account for the existence of the Epsilon garbage collector, which never frees memory; this is useful for benchmarking JVMs without the complication of garbage collection and also in environments where the application can be restarted when it runs out of memory: the JVM crash is in this some sense the actual garbage collector).

You could try executing `java.lang.System.gc` when the server stops: this may cause a GC run (note that there is no requirement that the system actually collect any garbage in such a scenario).  If a garbage collector will free any memory, about the only time it has to run is if there's not enough space to fulfill an object allocation request: therefore if the application stops allocating objects, there may not be a garbage collection run.

For performance reasons, most modern garbage collectors in the JVM wait until there's no more than a certain amount of free space before they collect garbage: this is because the time taken to reclaim all space is proportional to the number of objects which aren't reclaimable and for a great many applications, the pattern is that most objects are comparatively ephemeral, so the number of objects which aren't reclaimable is reasonably constant.  The consequence of that is that the garbage collector will do about the same amount of work in a "full" GC for a given application regardless of how much free space there is.

Comment: Thanks. I'm creating actors at server start and reusing them. There is no complex actors hierarchy, only 6 actors which are child of Akka root user actor.

Comment: Should I terminate actor system when server stops?

Comment: Terminating the actor system is probably not going to reduce memory consumption. I've updated my answer with why the assumption that GC will free space after every request is very likely inaccurate.

Comment: As long as the actors themselves are not accumulating a lot of state, then the memory consumption is probably not an issue: the GC will by and large do its job when it needs to.